# Detect iPad Safari or Zoom

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, mobile-safari

If I use the following to detect iPad Safari user, will it work if in future, I try to detect a Motorola Xoom or other tablet user, which might have similar widths.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css">
```

I mean how exactly will I identify the other tablet and use xoom.css or othertablet.css

I know the user-agent approach, but would want to avoid that. Please let me know if it is possible to implement using media queries only?

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish between desktop/ipad/other tablets(e.g. Xoom) through some feature detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't tell what specific device is being used based on media queries (and you shouldn't need to as they are all converging on the same standards)

Comment: So what is the best approach? I know this can be done through user-agent, but heard it is not the best way to detect ...What do you think?

Comment: Don't attempt to detect specific devices, just look for capability otherwise you end up with an endless cycle of attempting to support every new device or version of device that is released.

Comment: What exactly would capability mean? I am trying to identify device/browser as iPad Safari is going to be much different than Opera on Xoom..Right?

Comment: Wrong. Both implement HTML parsers and CSS engines.

Comment: So you mean to say that the rendering is going to be same for a page whether it is viewed on iPad Safari or Xoom Opera ? Is there any references to this anywhere else?

Comment: Do you have any reference to Xoom browser anywhere..think it is Opera ?

Comment: cannot find reference to Motorola Xoom on this page?

Comment: Why would you? It implements a web browser. Dictionaries don't list the name of every English speaker in in the world.

Answer (score 0):

We are starting to develop using Formfactor detection libraries such as [FormfactorJS](https://github.com/PaulKinlan/formfactor) - note, I created this.

The theory being using the same semantic HTML, you can specialize your CSS and Javascript using for a given class of device (smartphone, tablet, desktop etc) whilst also being cognizant of responsive design to individual device profile using Media Queries.

The good thing at least, is that you can specify your own detection algorithms, so you can detect different types of the same class of device (i.e, iPad or Xoom).  We chose to do this through userAgent checking in this case.  Why? because depending on the formfactor or device type you might want to offer optimised experiences.